# CALL FOR ACTION: Increase traffic by bringing over stackoverflow [salesforce] questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I had a thought after seeing how another site was implemented.  It seems the "Pro Webmaster StackExchange" site has the ability to migrate topics from the generic "stackoverflow" site.  This would greatly increase the traffic we get from search engines (today, half the topics i Google end up taking me to stackoverflow and half take me here).  Check out this example:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22430/how-to-hide-pages-from-google-crawler

Answer (score 9):

At least for questions on SFSE you can vote to close (with sufficient rep) if the question is more appropriate for another stackexchange.

Lacking the rep, you can flag a question to get a moderators attention to have them bring it over to this site.  Perhaps we should all start flagging questions on StackOverflow so they get migrated over to SFSE?

**Update**

Started a [related discussion on SO Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207484/how-to-redirect-users-to-alternate-stackexchange-for-question-that-were-formerly), might be good to get some "we agree" comments over there as well.

**Update 2**

After consulting the SO meta overlords it became fairly clear that (1) migrating old content really only make sense for really good questions, (2) you can only do it once, and (3) it totally spams the front page.  All in all, I think we could probably just let that one lie.

However, with regards to new questions we should all get together and start letting any new posters on Stack Overflow know about the new SFSE.  As far as I can tell the majority for posters are (1) first time posters, (2) were unaware of SFSE, and (3) preferred to re-ask their questions on SFSE.  This makes sense as the question volume and attention posters get (and votes answers get) is much higher on SFSE.

**CALL TO ACTION**

If the review queue is clear and there aren't any good questions to action, head over to the [Salesforce Stackoverflow Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/salesforce) and leave the following comment.

> Hi @, there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce
>   at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there!
>   :)

Comment: @saariko any chance we can bump this in the sidebar?

Comment: Action taken, comments made, a couple of answers given. This is a great call to action and should provide an influx of new members who will (hopefully) find a home in our helpful community.

Comment: Right on!  Thanks for driving that even further!  I hope this helps build the community here!